# Sql server after alter index performance down

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sqlperformance

Before indexing tables, i backup database and restore my test database with this backup. After than i created non cluster indexes on necessary tables.

Before index, query execute time around of 20 mins
After index, query execute time around of 10 secs.

And than i created these indexes at the prod table manually. But after create indexes execute time was around of 10 mins. When i research this problem on internet, i realised index column order is important for performance. Than i changed column orders. But performance still bad. around of 9 mins.

What is wrong?

(Sorry for bad english)

Comment: voted to move to dba.stackexchange.com. Be prepared to post **exact** table defintions, index definition, the query, and the query execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

From the question i understood that, Indexing increased performance on both Test and Prod environments but on Test it is taking 10 secs where as on prod it is taking 10 Mins approx.

On prod environment there are several factors to look at.

1. Any locks / blocks happening on the object.
2. index fragmentation levels
3. Last stats update happened.

If you post the query and the indexing strategy that would get you more help.